# Org agenda filter by property value

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

How can I create an agenda view that filters items based on the property `FOO`?

```
TODO Test
:PROPERTIES:
:FOO:    <2018-11-09 Fri 12:43>
:END:
```

I would use `org-agenda-skip-entry-if` for this but the only templates I see are these:

```
scheduled     Check if there is a scheduled cookie
notscheduled  Check if there is no scheduled cookie
deadline      Check if there is a deadline
notdeadline   Check if there is no deadline
timestamp     Check if there is a timestamp (also deadline or scheduled)
nottimestamp  Check if there is no timestamp (also deadline or scheduled)
regexp        Check if regexp matches
notregexp     Check if regexp does not match.
todo          Check if TODO keyword matches
nottodo       Check if TODO keyword does not match
```

None of them seem to do what I want. Is there a way to write a custom predicate with access to the entry's properties?

Answer (score 2):

See https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties.

I think you want the key sequence: C-c a m FOO={.*}

Comment: Oh, I want to be able to programmatically filter (in my skip function, or something like it). So for example in my case I want `FOO` to be in the past.  I thought that `FOO>=<timestamp>` would work for the interactive case, but apparently not—it has to be an exact match.